# CreateSymbolicLink works in Visual Studio, from IIS throws error 1314 (A required privilege is not held by the client)

Tags: c#, windows, iis

I've been scouring the Stack and the Net for a week and a half trying to figure out this problem with no success.

I have a website deployed to IIS 8 on Windows Server 2012. On my website I wrote a method to create a Directory structure on a different server.  In that structure are folders (works), shortcuts to files (works), and one symbolic link to a folder on a third server (ISSUE).

When running through Visual Studio this symbolic link is created without error. When published to IIS the symbolic link is not created.  Through Marshall.GetLastWin32Error() I found the Error code 1314 being thrown, A required privilege is not held by the client.

Things I've done so far:

1. Set the Application Pool identity to run as an Active Directory account I created.
2. Added the account to the Administrator group on all three servers.
3. Under Local Policy, added the account to the "Create Symbolic Links" policy on all three servers.
4. Under Local Policy, made sure "User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode" is disabled on all three servers.
5. Added IUSR to "Create Symbolic Links" policy on all 3 servers.

I'm assuming the issue is somewhere within IIS, since it runs wonderfully through VS.

**EDIT**

The method I'm calling is

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CreateSymbolicLink(string lpSymlinkFileName, string lpTargetFileName, int dwFlags);

CreateSymbolicLink("{FolderName}", @"//{servername}/{path}/", 0x1)
```

**EDIT 2**
I'm starting from scratch with the permissions and security settings and trying Jokies' steps.  Will hopefully have an update tomorrow

Comment: Have you tried running with the absolute path? Sometimes IIS doesn't set the correct current directory so you are creating paths where you don't think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After weeks of trying to diagnose this problem, the issue was a setting in IIS.

I went to the Application Pool, clicked on "Set Application Pool Defaults...", and the setting for "Load User Profile" was set to false. Setting this to true allowed IIS to create the symbolic link.

The odd part was in ProcMon I was seeing the domain account I created log in and make the folders and shortcuts before I made this change, it just wasn't making the symbolic link. I'm not entirely sure what this change did in the background, but whatever it was worked!

Answer (score 1):

The permission to create symbolic links needs to be granted either to the AppPool user itself, or to the IIS_IUSRS group. It is also necessary to ensure that the process that hosts the IIS service is restarted (just restarting IIS may not be sufficient if other services are also hosted in the same process. It may therefore be easiest just to reboot the server).

Once the above is done, it should be possible to create symbolic links from an IIS application (at least, it worked on my server).

Comment: The AppPool user was added to those permissions, but I'm not sure if the server was restarted. I will do that tonight and update if that works!

Answer (score 0):

Did you create symbolic link via run Process cmd.exe with mklink commandline?

1. I just create a new user and add it to domain Administrator group.
2. Then I login with that user and check whether mklink can be executed under this accound(work).
3. I just go back to the original IIS Server and set it as my application pool identity.
   Finally I am able to see the output tell me it has created symbolic link correctly.

I didn't change any permission for my authenticated user (IUSR).
[image]

[image]

[image]

Process monitor would help you check access denied error regarding system or application I/O. Maybe your environment require extra permission.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: I added an edit to show the method I used to create the link.  I also tried using ProcMon on all three servers and filter for kernel32.dll in the path, but never found anything of note with that. I'll use a few different filters to see if I find anything!